# Is there a XML editor similar to Inkscape built-in editor?

Tags: text-editing, xml, inkscape

I have been looking for a "perfect" XML editor, and today I realized the one used in Inkscape is exactely the way I would want, because:

- It has multi-panel (tree, attribute-list, and value text-box);
- Folding and highlight;
- The tags and XML syntax are kept invisible (and so protected from typos)

You can see what I mean here:

[image]

The only problem is... IT IS PART OF INKSCAPE, ONLY!

Does anyone know a similar program for standalone use, or a way to use that editor independently from inkscape?

Comment: I was not aware of the XML editor in InkScape.  Thanks for info!

Answer (score 0):

It may not look nice, but I use [gedit](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/screenshots.html) for all my programming needs. It's really bare-bones, but it has *tons* of plugins, so maybe you could find (or write) a few to suit your needs.